# React Router v4 - Redirect to all lowercase URL?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to detect URLs with capital letters and redirect them to the same URL with all lowercase letters.

So, something like '/products/Top/' would be redirected to '/products/top/'.

Is something like this possible with react-router-dom in React Router v4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
<Route sensitive 
       path="/:slug1*:slug2([A-Z]):slug3*/"
       render={props => <Redirect to={`${props.location.pathname.toLowerCase()}`}/>}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the following should work:

```
<Route sensitive={false} 
    path="/whatever/"
/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the wrong approach for SEO purposes.  You'll end up with different bookmarks from external sites.  For example, google won't realize that /CD and /cd are the same page, and it will throw off the analytics.  See checked answer for correct solution